# PHP & SQL search system variable issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables

I'm trying to create a player search system that searches through my SQL database. Everything is working but when I try to create the more info popup for the player the variables don't really work.

The PHP & JS code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#search-result', function(){
    $("#myDiv").fadeIn();
});

$(document).on('click', '#close', function(){
    $("#myDiv").fadeOut(); 
});
```

```html
<?php
$output = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $mysqli = NEW MySQLi ("localhost", "root", "", "textus");

    $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);

    $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE player_name LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 10");

    if($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {
        while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $player_name = $rows['player_name'];
            $kills = $rows['kills'];
            $current_team = $rows['current_team'];

            $output = " <div id=\"myDiv\">\n
                        <div id=\"player-popup-name\">$player_name</div>
                        <div id=\"close\">X</div>\n
                        <img id=\"player-popup-model\" src=\"http://www.minecraft-skin-viewer.net/3d.php?layers=true&aa=true&a=0&w=0&wt=0&abg=0&abd=0&ajg=0&ajd=0&ratio=8&format=png&login=$player_name&headOnly=false&displayHairs=true&randomness=104\"
                        \n
                        </div>\n 
                        \n

                        </div>\n


                        <a id=\"search-result\">\n
                        <div id=\"player-head\">\n</div>\n
                        <img id=\"search-result-player_head\" src=\"http://www.minecraft-skin-viewer.net/3d.php?layers=true&aa=true&a=0&w=310&wt=50&abg=330&abd=40&ajg=340&ajd=20&ratio=13&format=png&login=$player_name&headOnly=true&displayHairs=false&randomness=396\" height=\"45px\" width=\"45px\">\n
                        <div id=\"search-result-player_name\">$player_name</div>\n
                        <div id=\"search-result-team_name\">$current_team</div>\n
                        <div id=\"search-result-kills\">$kills</div>\n
                        <div id=\"search-result-banner\"></div>\n
                        </a>\n

     
    




                        ";
            echo "$output";
        }
    }else{
        $output = "<div id=\"no-result\">Ingen spelare hittad, sök igen...</div>";
        echo "$output";
    }
}
?>
```

This is how it looks like:

I don't have 10 rep so here is a gyazo link: http://i.gyazo.com/4395819df524124614246612aa2c5bd8.png

The search is working just as I want it but let's say I click the first result and want to se more info

This is what it looks like when I press the first result of the list:
http://i.gyazo.com/b2ab39572c0148b5376beb0c2928e800.png

And that is also how I want it. But here is the issue.
If I click any other results in the list I get the same variables as the first result. For example if I press the 3rd result I still get the same popup as I get if I press the first result.

If I change the search and click it still uses the first result variables.

So the thing I need help with is how I can make each result use it's own variables for the popup/more info div.

Comment: All the results have the same ID  - bad practice

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$(document).on('click', '#search-result', function(){
    $(this).find("#myDiv").fadeIn();
});

$(document).on('click', '#close', function(){
    $(this).find("#myDiv").fadeOut(); 
});
```

Comment: With youre suggestion it wont even work. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Hint: your code have some div's (for example 3) with equal id.

When you use this code:
$("#myDiv").fadeOut();  how js will understand what div of all it shoul be fadeOut ?

I think you should use something about "this" - construction $(this).find("#myDiv") should find div with id="myDiv" in a div, that have been clicked.

May be i have a mistake :(